# Why is text displayed behind absolute positioned image with CSS?

Tags: css, image, position, absolute, z-order

Using this HTML, I can't figure why the text displays behind the image:

```
<div style="position: relative">
<img src="image_url_here" style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;" />  
This is some text, drawn on the page after the image, why is it drawn behind the image?
</div>
```

?

Tested in Chrome on Mac & PC and IE on PC.

Answer (score 10):

This article can answer your question: [z-index explained](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/z-index-explained-how-to-stack-elements-using-css-7c5aa0f179b3)

**TL;DR:** Positioned elements are stacked over non-positioned elements, so just add  `position: relative` to the text you want stacked on top.

```html
<div style="position: relative">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="position:absolute; left: 10px;" />  
    <span style="position:relative">This is some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Try this or set as per your requirement

```
<div style="position: relative">
<img src="image_url_here" style="position:relative; top: 10px; left: 10px;" />  
This is some text, drawn on the page after the image, why is it drawn behind the image?
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be a bit toooo late to answer, but could be useful for somebody:
The solution is to set `z-index: -1;` to the image. Probably should wrap text in `<p>`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you set the image's position to absolute.

Comment: I know it's not meant to be humorous, but this answer cracks me up. +1

Comment: While this also made me smile, it unfortunately isn't helpful at all.